# Hero animation causes (minimal) overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

When a `Hero` contains a Column with `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`, on navigating to a new page, the content overflows. This even happens when navigating to the exact same page. So to illustrate this, see a rather ridiculous example below. In this example I get the message 'A RenderFlex overflowed by 0.0000172 pixels on the bottom.'
How can I prevent overflowing like this when using Hero animations?

Example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hero Overflow',
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hero overflow"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Hero(
          tag: "mytag",
          child: Card(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  PageRouteBuilder(
                    pageBuilder: (context, a , b) => MyHomePage()
                  )
                );
              },
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Hello world"),
                ],
              )
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by rounding errors that ocurred because `Rect` used `Float32List` instead of `Float64List`. You can take a look at [the issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27320).

It was fixed with [this PR](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/8565) and should already be in `stable`.

Comment: Thanks, I opened that issue. Thought it still needed more investigation though.

Comment: @JessedeWit The answer was not directed at you but meant to close this question and mark it as "answered".

Comment: Apparently the PR has been reverted, is there any solution for this?

Comment: @nicowernli I do not think so. Where did you see that?

Comment: there's still a conversation ongoing about this [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27320).

Comment: @pat64j It's closed. If you are having issues, it does not have to be related (not the same cause).